# How to Secure IBM WebSphere MQ 8.0 with Creds?

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using `IBM WebSphere MQ 8.x` and would like to secure it.

How can I secure my WebSphere Queue Messaging with *username/password*, so that only valid user can perform operations.

this is how I am accessing Queue right now

```
Context jndiContext = getInitialContext();
String qcf= getJMSDetailsBean().getQueueConnectionFactory();
QueueConnectionFactory qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup(qcf);
qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();
```

Could you please guide me on below:

1. How can I secure my MQ first?
2. After #1, How can I access MQ using `QueueConnectionFactory` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like many other things in technology there are multiple ways to accomplish the task you are asking about, below describes one method using the IBM MQ provided functionality.

---

To answer the simpler question first, if you want to pass a username and password to MQ you can call `createQueueConnection` with the arguments of username and password

```
createQueueConnection("username", "password")
```

---

On the MQ side if you can upgrade I would suggest you move to 9.0.0.5 LTS, if you cannot upgrade to v9.0 then I suggest you upgrade to 8.0.0.10 + IFIX [IT25591](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT25591), you can download the IFIX for this right from the APAR page at the top.

You do not mention which Operating system the queue manager is running on.  For most operating system versions you can configure the queue manager to validate credentials against either the Operating System (`IDPWOS`) or LDAP (`IDPWLDAP`).  You will point the `QMGR CONNAUTH` property to an `AUTHINFO` object with `AUTHTYPE` of either of the above options.

On Unix Operating Systems such as Linux you can configure `IDPWOS` authentication method (`AUTHENMD`) as either `OS` (uses crypt and compare against shadow password entries) or `PAM` (uses Pluggable Authentication Module).  If you go with `IDPWOS` I recommend `PAM` because it can provided crypt and compare support (same as the `OS` method) but also supports anything you can do with PAM, for example authenticate against Windows Active Directory.

For security you want to tell MQ to adopt the user that is authenticated, this is the `ADOPTCTX(YES)` setting on the `AUTHINFO` object.  You should configure the queue manager for `ChlauthEarlyAdopt=Y` in the `qm.ini` file (Note these are both now the default behavior in MQ v9.0.4 CD and higher and on 9.1.0.0 LTS (also 9.1.1 CD) and higher.

If you are sure you want every `SVRCONN` channel on the queue manager to require a valid username/password to be sent you can set `CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED)` on the `AUTHINFO` object.  If you need to be more granular you can set this to `CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL)` which means if a username and password is present, the password needs to be valid for the username, but it also means if a password is not provided MQ will not attempt authentication.  You may want this if you for example have some existing channels where you use a different authentication method such as TLS certificates, or a security exit.  If it is set to `OPTIONAL` at the `QMGR` level, you can setup `CHLAUTH` rules to uplift the setting to `CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED)` for specific channels.

Remember that if you make any changes to the queue manager `CONNAUTH` settings you need to run `REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)` for those to take effect.

If the MQ client is at MQ v8 or higher, the password if sent on a non-TLS channel will be protected by default with a 3DES encryption, the exception here is for Java and JMS clients you must enabled MQCSP mode (compatibility is the default).

The setting `PasswordProtection=always` can be set in the `qm.ini` to ensure that MQ enforces that the password must either be protected by the password protection feature or use a TLS channel with a non-NULL cipherspec.  This also means that on non-TLS channels any client that is less than v8 will be rejected.

---

I'll update this answer provide some example commands to implement the settings above, please let me know if this answer is going in the direction you are looking for?

---

I scanned the [Fix list for IBM MQ Version 8.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27043086) and found the following of interest either related to CONNAUTH or security in general that are fixed in versions later than 8.0.0.3, this is not a complete list there are many more:

8.0.0.5:

- [IT12825](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT12825): IBM MQV8: A CLIENT APPLICATION FAILS TO CONNECT TO A QUEUE MANAGER WITH ERROR AMQ9777: CHANNEL WAS BLOCKED.
- [IT11645](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT11645): AN IBM MQ V8 CLIENT CONNECTION IS INCORRECTLY ALLOWED WHEN PASSWORDPROTECTION=ALWAYS AND USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP=FALSE
- [CVE-2015-7473](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21984555): IBM WebSphere MQ Improper access control for some local MQSC commands
- [CVE-2016-0259](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21984561): IBM WebSphere MQ Improper access control for some display commands in local runmqsc

8.0.0.6:

- [CVE-2016-3052](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21998660): IBM MQ Java clients might send a password in clear text

8.0.0.7:

- [IT18052](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT18052): ChlauthEarlyAdopt modifications

8.0.0.8:

- [IT22419](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT22419): All username/password authentication requests hang. Queue manager is configured to request via PAM
- [IT21306](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT21306): Ensure consistency among mechanisms for enabling MQCSP authentication mode in Java
- [IT21384](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT21384): Setting COM.IBM.MQ.CFG.JMQI.USEMQCSPAUTHENTICATION=Y does not enable the MQCSP authentication mode after IT15833

8.0.0.10:

- [IT20275](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT20275): USERMAP CHLAUTH rules and ChlauthEarlyAdopt do not map to the correct user

8.0.0.11 (not release yet):

- [IT25591](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT25591): Connection to queue manager fails after upgrade to MQ 8.0.0.10, error log reports user missing CTRL authority on qmgr (AMQ8077)

Comment: Hi JoshMc, Thanks for the reply.
I am using Windows, Linux and working on MQ 8.0.0.3.
I am new to IBM MQ and not able to digest what you explained above. My requirement is, i want to secure existing applications (Queue Messaging) with just username and password.

Comment: I can not upgrade MQ to any other version due to restrictions. Could you please guide me how can I secure my queue, queue manager with creds for windows and ubuntu? (I would prefer same auth mechanism for both os)

Comment: @Joe You will want to go with 8.0.0.10 + the IFIX if you can't move to MQ v9.  There are many many problems with IBM CONNAUTH and only at versions later than 8.0.0.3 are these fixed.  Who in their right mind would ask you to implement security using versions of the software released over 3 years ago (18 June 2015)?  There are are a combined total of 46 security fixes in the releases from 8.0.0.4 - 8.0.0.10.  Do both your windows and ubuntu use a single account store (ex: ubuntu pointed to Windows AD for authentication)?  If not do you have windows AD available?

Comment: What other requirements do you have for supporting existing SVRCONN channels? Is this a new "green field" environment or are you adding this to an existing environment?  I provided a mid-level summary of what is needed. You should go out and try some of those things, but know that at 8.0.0.3 things are not very stable and some things do.may not work as expected.

Comment: Is it possible to configure MQ with creds I want. i don't want to use AD or LDAP or OS creds. I would like to configure username-password myself and when Java App wants to read messages from Queue, I will just provide creds I configured in MQ in `createQueueConnection("username", "password")`

Comment: No, that is not possible how you describe with vanilla CONNAUTH.   You could set up your own LDAP server or find a PAM library that would support looking up creds in some other store of your choosing.   Other options are client certs mapped to a MCAUSER, or a 3rd party commercial security exit.   I know that capitalware has one that can use a cred store that you maintain.

Comment: @Joe I added some APARs and CVEs fixed in version after 8.0.0.3 to try and provide some examples of things that are valuable security related fixes to have in place.  As to how you want to authenticate, my answer was describing how do it using IBM native CONNAUTH implementation and many of the fixes are required for the way I would recommend using it.  What you describe as I stated above is not possible with native IBM functionality.  Please try and explain what you are trying to accomplish in more detail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179530/discussion-between-joe-and-joshmc).

Comment: @Joe how did you do with your setup?   If you found the answer I provided useful please click the greyed out check mark to the left of the answer to accept if.   Let me know if you have any more questions.